# FromRawSql HasNoKey nullable bool conversion

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to create a raw sql query this way and map result to a ViewModel class:

Here is the view model class:

```
class MyViewModel
{
   public String field1 { get; set; }
   public bool? field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what i've put in dbcontext class (in OnModelCreating function):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyViewModel>.HasNoKey();
```

Here is my query:

```
   var query = db.Set< MyViewModel>(). FromRawSql("SELECT field1, null as field2 FROM MyTable");
```

I get an error about field2 because EF can't cast Null to field2. I do not understand why because field2 is nullable in MyViewModel.

I have also tried to put 0 or 1. I have a cast error Int32 vs bool. How can i make it work ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That should work fine, and it doesn't repro at all for me in EF Core 6.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bool type in T-SQL. `Bit` is used instead. Just remove `field2` from your SQL query

```
var query = db.Set< MyViewModel>(). FromRawSql("SELECT field1 FROM MyTable");
```

or try

```
class MyViewModel
{
   public string field1 { get; set; }
   public int? field2 { get; set; }
   public bool? field2b { get if (field2 != null) return Convert.ToBoolean(field2) 
  else return null;
   }
}
```

Or you can use case, add it to your SQL script

```
CASE 
    WHEN column2 IS NULL 
        THEN CAST(NULL AS bit)
        ELSE column2 
END AS field2
```

I can give more details, since I don't see what table are you querying.

Comment: In fact i want to calculte this field2 column which result is bool... And sometimes i will force true/false/null. How can i do that

Comment: Thanks. No way to do that in sql ?

Comment: @Bob5421 what do you mean?   Do  you want me to create a sql script too? Just use CASE for conversion. Or show your table , I can't create sql without seeing a table

Comment: No i just want to know how i can cast in the raw sql query, not in the viewmodel class. Thanks.